# Pandas column update

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update the column in panda. The goal is to change the format of the GPS co-ordinate.

column look like this.

```
 GPGGA_latitude
3205.719778
3205.719541
3205.719202
3205.71866
3205.718108
```

I am using a following to update the column.

```
gps[' GPGGA_latitude'] = -(pd.to_numeric((gps[' GPGGA_latitude'][:2])) \
  +pd.to_numeric(((gps[' GPGGA_latitude'][-(len(gps[' GPGGA_latitude'])-2):]))/60))
```

Currently, it's coming up with `KeyError: 2.0`

Any help on this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: Currently, the first element of you RHS expression is a two-row Series with index keys 0 and 1, and the second element is a three-row Series with index keys 2,3,4. How do you expect to sum them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to simulate the following.

Comment: y = str(3159.89025)
x = str(11558.370409)
longitude = float(x[:3]) +float((x[-(len(x)-3):]))/60
latitude = -(float(y[:2]) +float((y[-(len(y)-2):]))/60) @dyz

Comment: Well, clearly you are doing something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

The literal translation of your expression for the latitude, taken from your comment, is:

```
latitude = \
    -(gps[' GPGGA_latitude'].str[:2].astype(float)+\
      gps[' GPGGA_latitude'].str[2:].astype(float)/60)
```

I broke it into three lines to make the structure more clear. Honestly, the formula looks very suspicious. You can hopefully translate the expression for the longitude now.